# Channel info using discord.py

Tags: discord.py

How to know whether a channel is stage channel from channel id using discord.py

I tried to get channel information but could'nt get. Trying to create scheduled event using discord api so need to now channel type to enter entity type 1 for stage channel and 2 for voice/ text cha
nnel

Answer (score 0):

You could do type checking with `isinstance` in python:

```py
#Assuming you already have a instance of commands.Bot named client in this case

channel = client.get_channel(channelid)
if isinstance(channel, discord.StageChannel):
  #do something
```